# How to Run Genymotion's Virtual Device in VirtualBox

Tags: android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

Successfully install Genymotion, and run the Virtual Device.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAvxi.png

As we know that Genymotion is using VirtualBox for its virtualization engine. The Virtual Device in Genymotion also appears in VirtualBox Manager. But when i trying to run that Virtual Device through the VirtualBox Manager, i got this error.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/k77fn.png

So whats wrong with that? Can I run the Virtual Device in VirtualBox instead of Genymotion?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong: Genymotion virtual devices should not be run from VirtualBox. Use Genymotion to launch your devices.